# Node.js call function on require

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Is it possible to call a function in a Node.js module when it's required.

app.js

```
const Database = require('./database').Database;

const UsersModel = require('./model').Model; // pass the name = Users and database
const AdminsModel = require('./model').Model; // pass the name = Admins and database
```

database.js

```
export class Database {
    // some functions here
}
```

model.js

```
export class Model {
    onModelCreated(name, database) {
        this.name = name;
        this.database = database;
    }

    insert() {}
    find() {}
    delete() {}
    update() {}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean once or every time it is required somewhere? What are you trying to achieve with that? This sounds like a XY problem...

Answer (score 5):

Since `require` calls are cached, all the code inside the module is called once, when you require that module.

**abc/index.js**

```
const calledOnce = () => console.log('once');

calledOnce();

console.log('Also once');

module.exports = {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for the really lazy among us:

**call-function-on-require.js**

```js
(() => {
  console.log('call function on require');
})();
```

**index.js**

```js
require(`./call-function-on-require`);
```

**output**:

```
'call function on require'
```

**another solution**

or, if you like in `call-function-on-require.js`

```js
module.exports = () => {
  console.log('call function on require');
}

// index.js: require(`./call-function-on-require`)();
```